# Evaluate an integral using power series

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to develop power series solutions for the following integrals

$$\int_\phi^\pi\frac{(1-\nu \cos\theta)\,d\theta}{(1-2\nu \cos\theta+\nu^2)^{3/2}}$$

and

$$\int_\phi^\pi\frac{(\cos\theta-\nu)\,d\theta}{(1-2\nu \cos\theta+\nu^2)^{3/2}}$$

in terms of $\nu$, where $\phi=0$ if $0<\nu<1$ or some small value $\epsilon$ if $\nu=1$   (i.e. so that $1-\nu\cos(\theta)$ is not equal to $0$).
These integrals arise in connection with  the gravitational field of a ring, and appear in a mathpages.com article entitled "Gravity of a Torus". The author (Dr. Kevin S. Brown) gives solutions that converge rapidly for all values of $\nu<1$. Presumably these could be extended if $\nu=1$ with $\phi = \epsilon$.

I'm unable to replicate his results.

Dr. Brown, a prolific author, protects his privacy diligently, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

To paraphrase his paper slightly he states:

We can also express (the gravitational forces) as power series. Expanding the integral in powers of $\nu$ and dividing out the geometric series (?) gives (for the first integral)

$$ I=\frac {\kappa}{(1-\nu^2)}\left(1-{\nu^2\over4}-{3\nu^4\over64}-{5\nu^6\over256}-{175\nu^8\over16384} +...\right)$$

$$=\frac {\kappa}{(1-\nu^2)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k-1)4^{2k}}\left(\frac{(2k)!}{k!k!}\right)^2\nu^{2k}$$

where $\kappa$ is a constant involving $\pi$ etc (it's getting rather late). How is he getting this result? Please excuse my typos and formatting - new to Latex.

Comment: You either have some typos or you do not understand how integration variables work. If you integrate over the variable $\theta$, the resulting function you've defined **cannot** be a function of $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

As David H commented, I suppose that you are considering $$f(\nu)=\int_\phi^\pi\frac{(1-\nu \cos\theta)\,d\theta}{(1-2\nu \cos\theta+\nu^2)^{3/2}}$$ and not $f(\theta)$ which is no meaning since you integrate over $\theta$.

As you know, the antiderivative involves elliptic functions. Using a CAS, I obtained $$I=\int_0^\pi\frac{(1-\nu \cos\theta)\,d\theta}{(1-2\nu \cos\theta+\nu^2)^{3/2}}=\frac{(\nu -1) K\left(\frac{4 \nu }{(\nu +1)^2}\right)-(\nu +1) E\left(\frac{4 \nu
   }{(\nu +1)^2}\right)}{(\nu^2 -1) }$$ provided $$\left(\sqrt{1-\Re(\nu )^2}>\Im(\nu )\land \Im(\nu )+\sqrt{1-\Re(\nu
   )^2}>0\right)\lor \sqrt{1-\Re(\nu )^2}<\Im(\nu )\lor \Im(\nu )+\sqrt{1-\Re(\nu
   )^2}<0\lor \Re(\nu )>1\lor \Re(\nu )+1<0 $$ The corresponding Taylor series built around $\nu=0$ is $$f(\nu)=\pi\left(1+\frac{3 }{4}\nu ^2+\frac{45}{64}\nu ^4+\frac{175 }{256}\nu ^6+\frac{11025 
   }{16384}\nu ^8+\frac{43659 }{65536}\nu ^{10}+\frac{693693 }{1048576}\nu ^{12}+O\left(\nu ^{14}\right) \right)$$ which is a quite good approximation for $0 \leq \nu \leq 0.8$. For sure, adding more terms makes the fit better and better.

Concerning the coefficients, the numerators and denominators correspond respectively to sequences $A069955$ and $A056982$ of $OEIS$.

**Edit**

Taking into account your last edit, what has been done is  a Taylor series expansion of $(1-\nu^2)f(\nu)$ and not of $f(\nu)$ as I did in my answer. Doing the same, what I obtain for this expression is $$\pi\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\nu ^2-\frac{3 }{64}\nu ^4-\frac{5 }{256}\nu ^6-\frac{175 
   }{16384}\nu ^8-\frac{441 }{65536}\nu ^{10}-\frac{4851 }{1048576}\nu ^{12} +O\left(\nu ^{14}\right) \right)$$ which is exactly what Dr. Brown produced.

This finally write
$$f(\nu)=-\frac {\pi}{(1-\nu^2)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k-1)4^{2k}}\left(\frac{(2k)!}{k!\,k!}\right)^2\nu^{2k}$$ which means that $\color{red}{\kappa=-\pi}$.

From a computational point of view, noting $$a_k=\frac{1}{(2k-1)4^{2k}}\left(\frac{(2k)!}{k!\,k!}\right)^2$$ you could notice the simple recurrence relation $$a_{k+1}=\frac{4 k^2-1}{4 (k+1)^2}a_k$$ where $a_0=-1$. This would make any coding quite unexpensive.

Comment: Claude, you probably mean this sequence for the numerators: http://oeis.org/A069955. And just in case, the link for the denominators as well http://oeis.org/A056982

Comment: Thanks for your reply Claude. I edited the question last night to include more details about Dr. Brown's result, which is somewhat different than the CAS derived solution. In my  undergraduate days in engineering (five decades ago now) we were taught math on a "need to know" basis, so my background in formal mathematics is limited.

Comment: @PeterB. See my edit. I got the same as Dr. Brown.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It's exactly what I needed to know, and a great relief! Thanks again.

Comment: @PeterB. You are welcome ! The same applies to the other integral. If you need more help on this, just let me know. Cheers :-)